# Trouble with .height()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to simply render a div (#preloader) to the same height and width as the browser window. This seems to work fine for it's width, but I can't seem to process the height. Is there something i'm missing?

```
var winwidth = $(window).width();
var winheight = $(window).height();

$(#preloader).css({"width": winwidth + 'px', "height": winheight + 'px'});
```

Thanks

Comment: You forgot quotes in `$(#preloader)`, should be like `$('#preloader')`

Comment: @Sergio Those are called quotes. quote: `'` comma: `,`

Comment: I call them top commas :P

Comment: @Barmar, haha, sorry. Nice that other people are more awake than me. Thank you & corrected.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log winheight?

Comment: If that's the actual code, the width works because the default width of a div is already 100%. This is something that should be done with CSS anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, @Juhana - You're right, but I need the dimensions of the div to have set values so they can be easily animated, any idea why it's not picking up the values?

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. Set it to 100% height and width, then when you need to animate read its width and height in pixels.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was a `TypeError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sergio said, you missed the quotes around #preloader.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var winwidth = $(window).width();
    var winheight = $(window).height();

    $("#preloader").css({
        "width": winwidth + 'px',
        "height": winheight + 'px'
    });
});
```

Your actual script is fine. Here is it working: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMqmu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Another method to achieve this same affect is:

```
$(function(){
  var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    winWidth = $(window).width();

  $('#preloader').height(winHeight).width(winWidth);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLerd/)